# Postfix: transport_maps SMTP ignores header_checks

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, spam-prevention

I have a **working SMTP** setup in Postfix

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

All is good with the SMTP, however now Postfix **ignores the header_checks**

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

or

```
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

---

- Is there a **priority of operations**, like "use transport and stop"?
- If yes, what could be a way to apply **header_checks before transport**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why, but when I changed `transport` map from `*`:

```
* relay:[THE_SMTP_HOST]:587
```

to

```
specific_email@domain.tld relay:[THE_SMTP_HOST]:587
another_email@domain.tld relay:[THE_SMTP_HOST]:587
```

the `header_checks` started working.

(I tried `.domain.tld` - SMTP stopped working at all)